# PyCharm opens automatically

Tags: python, pycharm

I recently installed PyCharm. Now when I run a *.py file from the command line, PyCharm opens up and tries to create a project - every time! I close PyCharm, try to run the file from `cmd`, PyCharm opens back up and interferes. Is there any way to prevent this? Thanks.

Comment: Your a lifesaver Niladri. Thanks! That did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing `.py` file's association. By right clicking on any `.py` files > properties > general tab > Opens with > Change

Comment: Thank you so much! it was really troublesome.